# Can you move between readying a spell and resolving its effect to avoid mage slayer or counterspell?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, actions

I was wondering whether you could take a move action in the middle of your [Cast a Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#CastaSpell) action (similar to moving between attacks), but the answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95250/can-you-move-while-casting-a-spell) say no.

However, can you cast the spell as part of the [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready) action and use a trigger of "when I stop moving" or "when I move to that spot" (or something similar) and then expend the your reaction for the turn to release the spell?

And does this actually avoid triggering [Mage Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/mage-slayer) or a [Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) if the casting takes place out of sight or out of range?

> #### [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready)
>
> When you ready a spell, you **cast it as normal but hold its energy**, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs. To be readied, a spell must have a casting time o f 1 action, and holding onto the spell’s magic requires concentration.

> #### [Mage Slayer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/mage-slayer)
>
> When a creature **within 5 feet** of you **casts a spell**, you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against that creature.

> #### [Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell)
>
> Casting Time: 1 reaction, which you take when you **see** a creature **within 60 feet** of you **casting a spell**
>   You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell.

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate question.  It is worded very differently from mine and so I did not find it when searching (but maybe this question will turn up in someone else's search now).  FYI, the accepted answer (with clear support from a Jeremy) is that you can do this with a readied spell.